# Get data from Double click on non-editable Kendo Scheduler

Tags: bootstrap-modal, kendo-scheduler

I tried to get the data for empty kendo scheduler. Mean no event. I try to extract atleast start time, end time and date. I off the editable. mean I not use the window that kendo provided. I try to custom by using bootstrap modal.

here is my event delegate

```
$("#scheduler").delegate('.k-event', "click", function (e) {
  debugger;
});;
```

I can get the event on this scheduler, but i cant extract data without event.

Answer (score 0):

To get the underlying event object from event element you can get it's `data-uid` attribute and pass it to the [`occurrenceByUid`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/scheduler#methods-occurrenceByUid) method. Demo is available in the method description (check the link).